# Design Issue for web service call out from salesforce

Tags: web-services, salesforce, apex

For the scenario

As a user, whenever I try to generate or fetch codes, :

If, while generating codes via PUT callout, the request fails, then the system should identify that the put callout has failed and should not do subsequent GET callout to the codes which were not even created in the first place.

If, while generating codes via PUT callout, the request is successful, the system should wait for a while (30 secs to 1 min) and should not poll the Service API very frequently.

I have written a code thats call the PUT callout than after success of Put , calling the GET callout in future to retrieve the codes

Expected result is -

When PUT callout is sucess , system should wait for 30sec to 1 min to GET callout and retrieve all the data and store it in salesforce using scheduler and batch.

Comment: What's your question? What code are you using and what specific issue are you having with it?

Comment: My question is  When i use put callout than i get a response as success and on success i am calling Get callout and using batch to fetch the data , on server it takes 30 sec to 1 min , i need to schedule a job that runs like 10 sec , 10*2 sec ,20*2 sec untill it gets the records , if after 3 attempts record is not available than abort the job ?

Comment: How to write a cron experssion if first scheduler call would be system.now+ 15 sec than *2 for 2 times

Answer (score 0):

You can't schedule in Salesforce on a second-level cadence. The smallest allowable increment for a Schedulable job is fifteen minutes. Salesforce asynchronous jobs are always executed based on server load and are in a queue; you cannot control the time of their execution to the second.

While some approximation of this pattern could potentially be achieved using a Queueable chain, this pattern is not at all suited to the Salesforce architecture and really should be delegated to a middleware platform.

Comment: So what could be the possible approach if there is a requirement to check the callout if response status is processing .